# Websockets: scaling the codebase

Tags: ajax, performance, websocket

I have been given the task to see if it's feasible to convert an Ajax-based application to Websockets. Fundamentally, I'm clear on how to go about doing this. My question, is regarding best practices regarding scaling the codebase.

The application in question has about 80 different Ajax requests. Some of these are clearly user account related, some are related to the operation of the actual application and yet others are of a global nature (statistics, etc) and finally we have a chat service.

I'm wondering if there are any best practices on how to implement something like this. It's entirely possible to do all of this through the same WS channel, but I'm considering an approach where each functional group connects to a different WS channel/topic. I think this might help keep the codebase clean and separate the different functional areas, but on the other hand I have no idea about the performance implications of this.

I've looked around for tutorials on this subject but it seems that all Websocket tutorials are of a rather basic nature and don't focus on the issues of large scale websocket development from a point of keeping the codebase clean vs performance issues.

Thanks for any insights.

Comment: It seems like  you'd probably just want to do two things, First, use a layer on top of webSocket that turns it into a message passing scheme (socket.io could be that layer) so you can pass tagged messages.  Second, create a clean architectural scheme for register an interesting in a specific message name.  This could be modeled after `app.get()` in Express as an example of how to scale it across many separate modules.  You could even introduce the notion of middleware (the ability for code to preprocess messages before their event recipient got them) if that was useful.

Comment: One thing webSocket lacks that comes for free in ajax is true request/response where you know exactly which response belongs to which request. By default a webSocket does not have that. If that is something your clients need (it often is), then you would need to add some sort of transaction ID in order to be able to associate a given response with the request it came from. You'd include a unique transaction ID in each request and then the corresponding response would echo that back as part of the response, allowing an association to be made between the original request and the response.

Comment: Thank you both. I was planning on using WAMP (should have mentioned that right away). I've done some reading on it and think it should fit the bill nicely to build a message-ID system on top of it.